# javascript: regex pattern

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a regex that matches the string consisting of zero or more specified special characters(`.` and `_` ) with at least 2 alphanumerics.

I tried using `/[a-zA-Z._]{2,}&/`

But that is failing for
Eg  _. - failed to check at least 2 alphanumerics.

Expectation is -

```
.sds_erc - return True,

.e__u. - return True,

._u_ - return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[._]*(?:[a-zA-Z][._]*){2,}/
```

Any number of specials, as a prefix. Then, at least two alphanumerics followed by any number of specials.